# Dereference concatenated variable name

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I can do this, but it requires making a string of the variable then dereferencing it. Is there any way to shorten it to a simpler statement?

```
#!/bin/bash

FRUITS="BANANA APPLE ORANGE"

BANANA_COLOUR="Yellow"
APPLE_COLOUR="Green or Red"
ORANGE_COLOUR="Blue"

for fruit in $( echo $FRUITS ); do
    fruit_colour="${fruit}_COLOUR"
    echo $fruit is ${!fruit_colour}
done
```

I have tried lots of things like `${!"${fruit}_COLOUR"}` or `\$${fruit}_COLOUR` and many other variants, but the only way that has worked is by using a string.

Comment: The `!` syntax is a flag on variable substitution that basically says “substitute twice”. It doesn't change the requirement that what's inside the `${…}` must be a variable name. So no, you can't avoid using a variable that contains the name, unless you use a different method (`eval`).

Comment: You can also use associative arrays to do this much more cleanly. However its not a direct answer to your question, so just adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First off, you don't need to use `$(echo $FRUITS)` in the `for` statement. Using just  `$FRUITS` is enough.  Then you can do away with one of the lines inside the loop, by using `eval`.

The `eval` simply tells bash to make a second *evaluation* of the following statement (i.e. one more than its normal evaluation). The `\$` survives the first evaluation as `$`, and the next evaluation then treats this `$` as the start of a variable name, which resolves to "Yellow", etc.

This way you don't need to have a separate step which makes an interim string (which is what I believe was the main intent of your question).

```
for fruit in $FRUITS ;do
    eval echo $fruit is \$${fruit}_COLOUR
done
```

---

For an alternative method, as mentioned by *Patrick* in a comment (above), you can  instead use an *associative array*, in which an element's index does not need to be an integer. You can use a string, such as the name of a type of fruit.  Here is an example, using bash's associative array:

```
# This declares an associative array (It unsets it if it already exists)
declare -A colour
colour['BANANA']="Yellow"
colour["APPLE"]="Green or Red"
colour[MARTIAN ORANGE]="Blue"

for fruit in BANANA APPLE "MARTIAN ORANGE" ;do 
    echo "$fruit" is "${colour[$fruit]}"
done
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the bash-builtin `eval` to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash
FRUITS="BANANA APPLE ORANGE"
BANANA_COLOUR="Yellow"
APPLE_COLOUR="Green or Red"
ORANGE_COLOUR="Blue"

for fruit in $( echo $FRUITS );
do
    fruit_colour=${fruit}_COLOUR
    eval echo $fruit is \$${fruit_colour}
done
```

Note the backslashed-dollar sign.  Basically, the "eval" line causes `bash`
 to substitue for `$fruit` and `${fruit_color}`, then using `eval` to do a second round of substition before calling `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an eval statement. `eval` is a hint in most languages that you're doing something wrong.

```
foo_var=10
bar_var=12

# Build a string with your var name of choice
chosen_prefix='foo'
var_name="${chosen_prefix}_var"

# Use bang to deference it
chossen_value=${!var_name}
echo "Chossen value: ${chossen_value}"
```

Comment: I'd argue it's safer  to  use `eval` because at least people know it's dangerous, `${!var}` is about as dangerous in `bash` (also a command injection vulnerability if `$chosen_prefix` is under an attacker's control) and fewer people are aware of it. Try `var_name='a[$(uname>&2)0]' bash -c 'v=${!var_name}'`. Best approach here is the associative array.